# Download a large number of multiple files

Tags: python, multithreading, download, python-requests

I have a set of image url with index, now I want to parse it through a downloader that can download multiple files at a time to speed up the process.

I tried to put the file name and URL to dicts(name and d2 respectively) and then use requests and threading to do that:

```
def Thread(start,stop):
    for i in range(start, stop):
        url = d2[i]
        r = requests.get(url)
        with open('assayImage/{}'.format(name[i]), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)

for n in range(0, len(d2), 1500):
    stop = n + 1500 if n +1500 <= len(d2) else len(d2)
    threading.Thread(target = Thread, args = (n,stop)).start()
```

However, sometimes the connection is timed out and that file will not be downloaded, and after a while, the download speed decreases dramatically. For example, for the first 1 hour, I can download 10000 files, but 3 hours later I can only download 8000 files. Each file size is small, around 500KB.

So, I want to ask that is there any stable way to download a large number of multiple files? I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Dont try and download all at the same time. Pick some low number (4 maybe) and use a thread pool of that size to do the downloads. That way you wont create a huge number of threads and also you will be able to readily control how many images you are downloading at a time.

Comment: I have tried to use a low number of threads, but it's too slow (1 hour only 400 images).

Comment: That's very slow. 400 images = ~200mb. I'd expect 400 images in under a minute. Perhaps the issue is that the server is too slow, then throwing more threads at it may only make matters worse. How long does it take to download one image? You can experiment with how many threads to use and you will find a sweet spot. Perhaps its 8 perhaps its 64.